# Correct word to use for a suburban fence?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

What should I be using to describe a suburban fence?

Here is an image of what I am trying to find the right word for:

[image]

<sup>Author: [Greg O'Beirne](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Gobeirne) -  [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:JarrahFence_gobeirne.jpg)</sup>

I guess I might go with 篱笆 or 栏杆. Could I get the following:

- What main word should I go for?
- What other words could I use to convey the right meaning e.g 很高的一个木头栏杆?
- Which measure word should I be going for?

Answer (score 2):

[On the Hudong Baike page of 篱笆,](http://www.hudong.com/wiki/%E7%AF%B1%E7%AC%86)

> 又叫栅栏、护栏，用来保护院子的一种设施，一般都是由棍子、竹子、芦苇、灌木或者石头构成，在我国北方农村很常见。

That means, **篱笆 is a kind of facility to protect private yards, which is usually made of wood sticks, bambooes, reeds, shrubs or stones. It is common in rural areas in Northern China.**

So 篱笆 should be the most correct word to describe a fence.

[And 栏杆,](http://www.hudong.com/wiki/%E6%A0%8F%E6%9D%86&prd=button_doc_jinru)

> 栏杆是建筑物的楼、台、廊、梯等边沿处的围护构件，具有防护功能，兼起装饰作用。

So it's related to buildings (although it can be in other places, like a path in a mountain).

Google Translate translates 栏杆 into railing, not fence.

**Update:**

The measure word, well, maybe 一排篱笆 will work. But as a Chinese I can't remember any measure word that is special for 篱笆...

Comment: What is the normal word for the dividers that separate road traffic from the bicycle lane? I would have called them 栏杆.

Comment: yes, it can be.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I've been using

```
藩篱
```

No idea if it is suitable, or what measure word that goes with it. 个 possibly ;)